# JAXB Unmarshal Strange Behaviour

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, annotations

Apologies if this questions seems repeated, but I had pored over hundreds of forums and posts on this context and I do seem to be having things apparently correct and compliant to all JSR and other comments/posts on this topic.

But before I break my laptop, I wanted to see if other pairs of eyes can help in anyway.

Here is the DTD for my XML

```
<!ELEMENT prodcat (product*)>
<!ELEMENT product (name, description?, composition+, commercial?,  prodMeta*)>
<!ELEMENT name EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT description EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT composition ((atomicProduct|resource)+, composition*)>
<!ELEMENT commercial EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT prodMeta EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT atomicProduct EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT resource EMPTY>

<!ATTLIST product
    id ID #REQUIRED
    discoverable (true|false) #REQUIRED
>

<!ATTLIST composition
    type (include|mutex) #REQUIRED
>

<!ATTLIST commercial
    isoCurrencyCode CDATA #REQUIRED
>

<!ATTLIST prodMeta
    name CDATA #REQUIRED
    value CDATA #REQUIRED
>

<!ATTLIST atomicProduct
    id IDREF #REQUIRED
>

<!ATTLIST resource
    id CDATA #REQUIRED
>
```

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE prodcat SYSTEM "prodcat.dtd">

<prodcat>
    <product id="PRD_14" discoverable="true">
        <name>UniFi Advance 30Mbps</name>
        <composition type="include">
            <atomicProduct id="PRD_9"/>
            <atomicProduct id="PRD_11"/>
            <atomicProduct id="PRD_13"/>
        </composition>
        <commercial isoCurrencyCode="MYR"/>
        <prodMeta name="Category" value="Bundle" />
    </product>

    <product id="PRD_9" discoverable="true">
        <name>HyppTV Residential</name>
        <composition type="include">
            <atomicProduct id="PRD_5" />
            <composition type="mutex">
                <atomicProduct id="PRD_6" />
                <atomicProduct id="PRD_7" />
                <atomicProduct id="PRD_8" />
            </composition>
        </composition>
    </product>
</prodcat>
```

The pojos are annotated with `@XmlAttribute` and `@XmlElement` respectively. But for some reason, only `commercial` and `prodMeta` alone refuse to be parsed... No errors, No Exceptions, No complaints... Just wont be touched!!! this is very strange.

Really need help.

Comment: Please clarify what : "only commercial and prodMeta alone refuse to be parsed" means and what your *exact* problem is. I *think* you might miss a mandatory element in your input xml. Most likely you are having a `product`node without `comosition`.

Comment: What does the Java class you are unmarshalling to look like?

Comment: Thanks @jah.... I finally manage to resolve the mystery. The XML and Pojos were all correct. Just that in the deployment, an older version of the DTD was in place which didnt have `commercial` and `prodMeta` elements defined. It was very difficult to troubleshoot since there were no errors or exceptions or any signs of breaking.... but this one threw everyone off their game :)

Answer (score 1):

I finally manage to resolve the mystery. The XML and Pojos were all correct. Just that in the deployment, an older version of the DTD was in place which didnt have commercial and prodMeta elements defined. It was very difficult to troubleshoot since there were no errors or exceptions or any signs of breaking